# Decreasing function code with lambda function

Tags: php, optimization, lambda

I have a function that will decrease your (optimize) the amount of code lines that this has. This function has some fragments that are repeated.

Could reduce this code using lambda function?

This is my function code:

```
static function get_all_category_with_widgets( $status = 'all' ) {
            $all_categories = SB_Central::get_categories();
            $all_widgets    = SB_Settings::get_sb_widgets(); // Get all widgets from options variable.

            foreach ( $all_categories as $category_key => $category_value ) {
                foreach ( $all_widgets as $widget_value ) {
                    // Create one widget
                    $widget = array_merge($widget_value['widget'], array ( 'id' => $widget_value['id'], 'status' => $widget_value['status']));

                    // In this case save active and disable.
                    if ( $status == 'active_and_disable' && ( $widget_value['status'] == 'active' || $widget_value['status'] == 'disable' )) {
                        if ( $category_value[ 'category_title' ] == $widget_value[ 'category' ][ 'title' ] ) {
                            $all_categories[ $category_key ][ 'widgets' ][ ] = $widget; // Save widget
                        }
                    } elseif ( $status == 'active' && $widget_value['status'] == 'active' ) {
                        if ( $category_value[ 'category_title' ] == $widget_value[ 'category' ][ 'title' ] ) {
                            $all_categories[ $category_key ][ 'widgets' ][ ] = $widget; // Save widget
                        }
                    } elseif ( $status == 'disable' && $widget_value['status'] == 'disable' ) {
                        if ( $category_value[ 'category_title' ] == $widget_value[ 'category' ][ 'title' ] ) {
                            $all_categories[ $category_key ][ 'widgets' ][ ] = $widget; // Save widget
                        }
                    } elseif ( $status == 'deleted' && $widget_value['status'] == 'deleted' ) {
                        if ( $category_value[ 'category_title' ] == $widget_value[ 'category' ][ 'title' ] ) {
                            $all_categories[ $category_key ][ 'widgets' ][ ] = $widget; // Save widget
                        }
                    } elseif ( $status == 'all' ) {
                        if ( $category_value[ 'category_title' ] == $widget_value[ 'category' ][ 'title' ] ) {
                            $all_categories[ $category_key ][ 'widgets' ][ ] = $widget; // Save widget
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return $all_categories;
        }
```

And this is the code that always i have repeat:

```
if ( $category_value[ 'category_title' ] == $widget_value[ 'category' ][ 'title' ] ) {
                            $all_categories[ $category_key ][ 'widgets' ][ ] = $widget; // Save widget
                        }
```

If you know a better way to reduce this code will be welcome.

Comment: All that `IF`'s can all be grouped into one IF statement.

Comment: Please explain why you think "fewer lines" always correlates with "optimize".

Comment: @lightness Racess, It gives me the impression that I have some repeated statements that from another point of view I can decrease the amount of lines. Maybe I interpreted well, but what I want is to see the possibility of reducing the number of lines if this is possible. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your if/elseif/elseif.... block with the following much terser representation

```
if ( $category_value[ 'category_title' ] == $widget_value[ 'category' ][ 'title' ] ) {
    switch ($status){
        case "active_and_disable":
            // set if widget statis is active or disable
            if( $widget_value['status'] == 'active' || $widget_value['status'] == 'disable' ){
                $all_categories[ $category_key ][ 'widgets' ][ ] = $widget; // Save widget
            }
            break;
        case "all":
            // always set
            $all_categories[ $category_key ][ 'widgets' ][ ] = $widget; // Save widget
            break;
        default:
            // set when status == widget status
            if ($status == $widget_value['status']){
                $all_categories[ $category_key ][ 'widgets' ][ ] = $widget; // Save widget
            }
            break;
    }
}
```